# Communication from Diretives to Controller in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

I am new to angularjs. I have following code , Now i want to access object of map in controller. here i am not able to know, how to pass it to controller?

My Custom Directive :

```
angular.module('demoApp.directives', []).
    directive('mapCanvas', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
                var  mapOptions = {
                    center:new google.maps.LatLng(22.772323, 78.214897) ,
                    zoom: 5,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
                var map = new google.maps.Map(elem[0], mapOptions);

            }
        }
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a function in your `scope` and pass a `map` as an argument.

In a scope: 
`$scope.getMap = function(map){ // do something with a map};` .

In a directive , after `map` definition add: `scope.getMap(map)`

Comment: sorry, i am not getting your point. how can i add map object to scope.

Comment: @user2834766 add this in your controller: `$scope.getMap = function(map){ // do something with a map}; .`

Comment: @user2834766 and this: `scope.getMap(map)` in your directive after `var map = ...` line

Comment: yeah its working :) thanks :)  can u explain me this line scope.getMap(map)